# How would I detect website clicks in the program in Qt QWebView?

Tags: c++, qt, qwebview

I thought about using a click event, but I noticed the screen click event doesn't emit on button presses, so I'm not sure if it will emit on website presses. An issue with this is if the user scrolls up or down -- then I won't know where the buttons are.

I thought about using network requests, but that would require writing a server just to detect button presses, unless I repeatedly check to see if it's been pressed, but that seems rather inefficient, too.

So, how would I go about detecting events on a website in QWebView? I understand PhoneGap can do it, but I'm not sure how to do it in Qt.

Comment: I found the answer. It's on this page `https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwebkit/qtwebkit-bridge.html`

Answer (score 0):

Qt has a way, using the Qt Network Bridge.

There is an overview here:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebkit-bridge.html